# Functionality of fork()

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

System information: I am running 64bit Ubuntu 10.10 on a 2 month old laptop.

Hi everyone, I've got a question about the `fork()` function in C.  From the resources I'm using (Stevens/Rago, YoLinux, and Opengroup) it is my understanding that when you fork a process, both the parent and child continue execution from the next command.  Since `fork()` returns `0` to the child, and the process id of the child to the parent, you can diverge their behavior with two if statements, one `if(pid == 0)` for the child and `if(pid > 0)`, assuming you forked with `pid = fork()`.

Now, I am having the weirdest thing occur.  At the beginning of my main function, I am printing to `stdout` a couple of command line arguments that have been assigned to variables.  This is this first non assignment statement in the entire program, yet, it would seem that every time I call `fork` later in the program, these print statements are executed.

The goal of my program is to create a "process tree" with each process having two children, down to a depth of 3, thus creating 15 total children of the initial executable.  Each process prints it's parent's process ID and its process ID before and after the fork.

My code is as follows and is properly commented, command line arguments should be `"ofile 3 2 -p"` (I haven't gotten to implementing `-p/-c` flags yet":

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 5)//checks for correct amount of arguments
    {
        return 0;
    }

    FILE * ofile;//file to write to
    pid_t pid = 1;//holds child process id
    int depth = atoi(argv[2]);//depth of the process tree
    int arity = atoi(argv[3]);//number of children each process should have

    printf("%d%d", depth, arity);

    ofile = fopen(argv[1], "w+");//opens specified file for writing



    int a = 0;//counter for arity
    int d = 0;//counter for depth
    while(a < arity && d < depth)//makes sure depth and arity are within limits, if the children reach too high(low?) of a depth, loop fails to execute
                                  //and if the process has forked arity times, then the loop fails to execute
    {
        fprintf(ofile, "before fork: parent's pid: %d, current pid: %d\n", getppid(), getpid());//prints parent and self id to buffer
        pid = fork(); //forks program
        if(pid == 0)//executes for child
        {
            fprintf(ofile, "after fork (child):parent's pid: %d, current pid: %d\n", getppid(), getpid());//prints parent's id and self id to buffer
                    a=-1;//resets arity to 0 (after current iteration of loop is finished), so new process makes correct number of children
            d++;//increases depth counter for child and all of its children
        }
        if(pid > 0)//executes for parent process
        {
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);//waits on child to execute to print status
        fprintf(ofile, "after fork (parent):parent's pid: %d, current pid: %d\n", getppid(), getpid());//prints parent's id and self id to buffer
        }
        a++;//increments arity counter
    }


    fclose(ofile);
}
```

When I run  `gcc main.c -o ptree` then `ptree ofile 3 2 -p`, the console is spammed with `"32"` repeating seemingly infinitely, and the file `ofile` is of seemingly proper format, but far far too large for what I think my program should be doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget to `fflush(NULL);` just *before* the `fork()`

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure why the `fputs` to `stdout` would be executed for the children, and don't have a Unix box to hand to verify/test.

However, the following jumps out:

```
int depth = *argv[2];//depth of the process tree
int arity = *argv[3];//number of children each process should have
```

You are taking the ASCII codes of the first character in `argv[2]` and `argv[3]` as your `depth` and `arity`, so your code is trying to spawn `50^51` processes instead of `2^3`.

What you want is:

```
int depth = atoi(argv[2]);//depth of the process tree
int arity = atoi(argv[3]);//number of children each process should have
```

Once you fix this, `bleh[0] = depth` and its twin will also need correcting.

**edit** Although this is not a problem right now, you're cutting it pretty close with the length of some of the things you're `sprintf`ing into `obuf`. Make some of the messages just a little bit longer and [Kaboom!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow) At the very least you want to use `snprintf` or, better yet, `fprintf` into the file directly.

**edit** I've just realised that `fork`, being an OS function, most probably isn't aware of internal buffering done by C I/O functions. This would explain why you get duplicates (both parent and child get a copy of buffered data on `fork`). Try `fflush(stdout)` before the loop. Also `fflush(ofile)` before every `fork`.

Comment: The code runs more reasonably now, but the 32 still prints out multiple times, whereas it should only be executing once since it is not inside of a loop, and it is before all fork commands, and ofile is still wildy larger than it should be, with a total of 34 child processes, whereas it should be 2^3+2^2+2^1=14 child processes. I've edited my source code to reflect the changes. Any ideas?

Comment: Just added another suggestion at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 errors in your code :

1)

```
  int depth = *argv[2];//depth of the process tree
  int arity = *argv[3];//number of children each process should have
```

With this code you are getting the first char of the strings argv[2] and argv[3].
A correct code must be like that :

```
int depth = atoi(argv[2]);
int arity = atoi(argv[3]);
```

2)

```
bleh[0] = depth;
fputs(bleh, stdout);
bleh[0] = arity;
fputs(bleh, stdout);
```

You can do something like that `bleh[0] = (char) depth;` but you'll just keep the first byte of your integer and its not that you want to do i guess, if you want to print the whole integer, simply use :

```
printf("%d\n%d", depth, arity);
```

I just tryied your code with those modifications and it seems to work well :)

Anhuin

Comment: Thanks! The code runs more reasonably now, but the 32 still prints out multiple times, whereas it should only be executing once since it is not inside of a loop, and it is before all fork commands, and  ofile is still wildy larger than it should be, with a total of 34 child processes, whereas it should be 2^3+2^2+2^1=14 child processes.  I've edited my source code to reflect the changes.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't print out numbers using that code at the start of your function. It's probably invoking undefined behavior by passing a non-string to `fputs()`. You should use `sprintf()` (or, even better, `snprintf()`) to format the number into the string properly, and of course make sure the buffer is large enough to hold the string representation of the integers.

Also, you seem to be emitting text to the file, but yet it is opened in binary mode which seems wrong.

Comment: I would argue that a portable program *always* uses binary mode with `fopen`. Certainly if your target is POSIX it doesn't matter since binary and text modes are required to be identical, but always using binary mode will ensure that your program doesn't break if you compile it on windows (it might need to be prepared to see and strip or interpret `\r` characters though).