# Forking and Process Management

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

System information: I am running 64bit Ubuntu 10.10 on a 2 month old laptop.

Hi everyone, I've got a question about the fork() function in C.  From the resources I'm using (Stevens/Rago, YoLinux, and Opengroup) it is my understanding that when you fork a process, both the parent and child continue execution from the next command.  Since fork() returns 0 to the child, and the process id of the child to the parent, you can diverge their behavior with two if statements, one if(pid = 0) for the child and if(pid > 0), assuming you forked with pid = fork().

Now, I am having the weirdest thing occur.  At the beginning of my main function, I am printing to stdout a couple of command line arguments that have been assigned to variables.  This is this first non assignment statement in the entire program, yet, it would seem that sometimes when I call fork later in the program, this print statement is executed.

The goal of my program is to create a "process tree" with each process having two children, down to a depth of 3, thus creating 14 total children of the initial executable.  Each process prints its parent's process ID and its process ID before and after the fork.

My code is as follows and is properly commented, command line arguments should be "ofile 3 2 -p" (i haven't gotten to implementing -p/-c flags yet":

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 5)//checks for correct amount of arguments
    {
        return 0;
    }

    FILE * ofile;//file to write to
    pid_t pid = 1;//holds child process id
    int depth = atoi(argv[2]);//depth of the process tree
    int arity = atoi(argv[3]);//number of children each process should have

    printf("%d%d", depth, arity);

    ofile = fopen(argv[1], "w+");//opens specified file for writing



    int a = 0;//counter for arity
    int d = 0;//counter for depth
    while(a < arity && d < depth)//makes sure depth and arity are within limits, if the children reach too high(low?) of a depth, loop fails to execute
                                  //and if the process has forked arity times, then the loop fails to execute
    {
        fprintf(ofile, "before fork: parent's pid: %d, current pid: %d\n", getppid(), getpid());//prints parent and self id to buffer
        pid = fork(); //forks program
        if(pid == 0)//executes for child
        {
            fprintf(ofile, "after fork (child):parent's pid: %d, current pid: %d\n", getppid(), getpid());//prints parent's id and self id to buffer
                    a=-1;//resets arity to 0 (after current iteration of loop is finished), so new process makes correct number of children
            d++;//increases depth counter for child and all of its children
        }
        if(pid > 0)//executes for parent process
        {
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);//waits on child to execute to print status
        fprintf(ofile, "after fork (parent):parent's pid: %d, current pid: %d\n", getppid(), getpid());//prints parent's id and self id to buffer
        }
        a++;//increments arity counter
    }


    fclose(ofile);
}
```

When I run "gcc main.c -o ptree" then "ptree ofile 3 2 -p", the console is spammed with "32" a few times, and the file "ofile" is of seemingly proper format, but a bit too large for what I think my program should be doing, showing 34 child processes, when there should be 2^3+2^2+2^1=14.  I think this is somehow related to the statement that is printing "32", as that would seem to possibly spawn more forks than intended.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this isn't a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459685/functionality-of-fork, it needs to be made clearer why it isn't.

Comment: Well, the answers there were focusing on some errors I made that are apparently unrelated to my central question, why this print statement for these 32's are being executed multiple times, when they are before my forks and loops.  All the answers there focused on my error concerning not using atoi() and having convoluted file output, neither of which answers that question.  I decided to repost with the changes the people there suggested I make, in hopes of not distracting any potential answerers from my central question again.

Comment: I'd beg to differ that the code is "properly commented", when it contains comments like "a++;//increments arity counter" and "pid = fork(); //forks program"!

Comment: I'm very new to C graham, I like to make sure almost everything is commented so that when I am reading my own code, I know exactly what a statement is and refers to, even without having to look at the actual code.  I'm sure your industry standards and whatnot are very useful in keeping code uncluttered amongst professional programmers, but cut us students some slack for a bit eh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call printf, the data is stored in a buffer internally.  When you fork, that buffer is inherited by the child.  At some point, (when you call printf again, or when you close the file), the buffer is flushed and data is written to the underlying file descriptor.  To prevent the data in the buffer from being inherited by the child, you can flush the FILE * before you call fork, via fflush.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.  I can't even find a reference to that situation occuring in my textbook, though it may very well be there, nor did my teacher ever mention such a thing.  I'm sure I never would have figured that out on my own.  Cheers!

Comment: Also worth noting that the buffer is automatically duplicated when you fork, which is why you get duplicate output.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what William was insinuating with the buffer being inherited by the child.  Thanks for your input though Douglas.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `stdout` is line-buffered by default, which means that if you always finish your `printf()` formats with a `\n`, you won't see the problem.  Since this is quite common, it might be why the textbook / teacher didn't mention the issue.

Comment: It is not quite correct to say that stdout is line-buffered by default.  *If* stdout is associated with a tty, then it is line-buffered by default.  But in the majority of cases stdout is associated with a pipe, and in that case it is block buffered by default.  It is also block buffered by default when associated with a regular file.